# overloading directory structure for maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, continuous-integration, parallel-builds

I'm working with Jenkins & Maven
I'm looking for a way that would also me not to download commonly used artifacts like org.apache, org.springframework... but will allow me to redownload/rebuild only my own company artifacts.
I am aware of the following options -

1. running jobs with their own local maven repository, but that will download replicate the common components many many times.
2. deleting/purging the com.myCompany package from the machine repository - but that would have 'slave machine' wide effects on other builds running in parallel.

My idea is to use a job maven repository but have softlinks to the machine .m2 repository for all the artifacts packages **except** com.myCompany, it seems that this would be a fair solution. Basically giving me the option perform directory "overloading" for com.myCompany directory

Does anybody know of any other solution for this problem or have implemented such a scheme?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a binary repository like Artifactory, you can create remote repositories to host your commons artifacts.
Next, you can configure the [Includes Pattern](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Common+Settings#CommonSettings-IncludesandExcludesPattern) to filter your commons versions.
Your build will stop downloading them if your local version (.m2) is the same than the remote repository version.

Comment: I wish to solve it locally without requiring an additional artifact repository aside from my company main one